# Python Request wait for page to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, beautifulsoup

Well i am trying for a few days to Request with loading, cuz the site need to loads some staff for a second and then i can reach the data i need,
firstly i have tried to use :

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
time.sleep(3)
html.read() #even without this line it would give me the same resault.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

and it didn't work, i must to find a way to reach those elements after loading.
i already tried Selenium but its so slow compared to requests and selenium always have bugs that the connection were closed from Remote controlled or something like that, i must to find a solution to do it, thank you very much
Thank in advance!

Comment: post the url and the output you need.

Answer (score 2):

Is the page using JavaScript? If so, you can wait for all the time of the world, you are using an headless browser and you won't get anything. That means it won't load any JavaScript or any client-side code.

You're best option would be to use something like Selenium. It's slower because it's actually doing the work you intend to do.